# Count for datetime object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to iterate over DateTime properties on objects in a List collection...

Ex. a tree view that lists the a Name with all its Courses underneath works fine:

```
    // Sorting on name with the courses beneath it:
    // *list* is a List<ClsStandholder>;
    private void ShowNameWithCourses()
    {
        treeViewList.Nodes.Clear();
        for (int i=0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            treeViewList.Nodes.Add(list[i].name);
            for (int j=0; j < list[i].courses.Count; j++) {
                treeViewList.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(list[i].courses[j]);
            }
            treeviewList.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
```

That works perfect... where I am having trouble is trying to sort on date and iterate through a count of the dates.

```
for (int j=0; j < list[i].SubscriptionDate. // how do i put some sort of count for this?
```

There seems to be no property to loop over all the dates entered.

Comment: What is the type of the `list` variable, and is the `SubscriptionDate` property just a `DateTime`?

Comment: The list is just a List<ClsStandholder> that holds values such as name, surface, number, Subscription date. The SubscriptionDate is indeed a DateTime object.  I can call all the other properties with a count, but not sure how to use this DateTime object in my loops.

Comment: so what are your relationships here? From your code it looks like one name is related to N courses and 1 date - in this case there is nothing to count, since there is only one date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a collection of dates in order to be able to use `Count`. You are saying that the list is indeed a `List<ClsStandholder>` and inside you have courses which is a collection but `SubscriptionDate` is a single `DateTime` property. How about declaring it as a collection (the same way you've done it for the `courses` collection):

```
public IList<DateTime> SubscriptionDates { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The two approaches look like quite different problems. It could be that all `clsStandholder`s within `list` have the same `SubscriptionDate`.

I would recommend making a...

```
Dictionary<DateTime,List<ClsStandholder>>;
```

..then iterating through each item in list and adding it to the corresponding list within the dictionary. Then you can iterate through the dates...

Answer (score 0):

The issue Tonz, is that your `list` variable is the collection, and the `SubscriptionDate` is a single property value on each item in the list. Since the property exists once for each item, there is no `Count`.

You could loop through the items, and build a collection of the `SubscriptionDates` and iterate over them...